# How to check mandatory fields in the request of SoapUI

Tags: soapui

Suppose there is wsdl file, and import wsdl into `SoapUI` tool. It will create one project right?

In the soap request, how to find mandatory fields if the request contains many elements?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

Right click on the project, create test suite, create test case and add SOAP Request test step. Then, you can choose the operation that you needed. The following wizard will be shown.

[image]

**Approach 1** : *Do not create optional elements in the request*
You can see `Create optional elements` in the screen shot above(marked at #5), do not click on the check box, you get the request created without optional elements i.e., only **mandatory** elements are present in the request.

**Approach 2** : *By looking at the comments in the request*
Even you click the above mentioned check box, request is created with all the possible elements i.e., both mandatory and optional elements. And you would find an explicit comment for each optional element(as shown in the screen shot #6). So, you won't see any comment for **mandatory** element.

**Any other way to find `if the request is valid`**
In the request editor, you can key in with combination of `Alt+v` or `right click and validate` which will show whether any errors in the request are present.

Hope this helps.